# Is there a way to specify a wildcard export in JSdoc?

Tags: node.js, jsdoc

In my project, the database models are dynamically loaded and exported from the `models` folder.

What I want to do is to specify in the JSdoc that **any** `module.exports` property is a type of `Sequelize.Model`. I looked at the docs, but could not find anything that allows some type of wild card.

Is this even possible with JSdoc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, when I don't know the type, I don't provide one. If you feel you must, and you don't know what it is at all your best choice is `Object`.

If you know its a key value pair and all values ares strings `Object<string>`.

There are also more advanced types like `@record` and `@interface` which I will leave to the [documentation](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/wiki/Annotating-JavaScript-for-the-Closure-Compiler) to describe.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. `Object<String, Sequelize.Model>` worked, but for some reason I get the `Model` instance instead of the class when I import it. However, this might be a conflict with JSdoc and Sequelize.Model specifically and not a JSdoc exclusive issue.